# Async and a single instance class working with Models

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am using a WebApi delegating handler to forward requests to another server.

```
protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string requestContent = string.Empty;
    UriBuilder forwardUri = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
    //remove the proxy port and replace with an Http port
    forwardUri.Port = 1900;
    //send it on to the requested URL
    request.RequestUri = forwardUri.Uri;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
    {
        request.Content = null;
    }
    try
    {
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            ManageOnlineRequests(response);
        }
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ManageOfflineRequests(request);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but I am pseudo caching some data on the `ManageOnlineRequests`. For that purpose I am using a single instance class that contains a representation of the models I want to keep, so that I can mock the response and return those when in offline mode `ManageOfflineRequests`.

The question I have is : Since this is a Async method that contains a `await` inside, is there any potential issues accessing the lists I have inside singleton class called by the `ManageOnlineRequests` and `ManageofflineRequests`?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by issues? do you mean race conditions?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yuval said, this is unrelated to `async-await`. If you plan on using these lists concurrently you need to make sure they are thread-safe.

Now, the simplest option is to use a `lock`, however if you are using `List<T>` specifically it's guaranteed to be thread-safe as long as you are **only reading** from it and not updating it concurrently:

> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read

From [List Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

A better solution would be to use the `ImmutableList<T>` out of `Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable` which is guaranteed to be thread-safe since it's immutable.

Answer (score 1):

> Since this is a Async method that contains a await inside, is there
>   any potential issues accessing the lists I have inside singleton class
>   called by the ManageOnlineRequests and ManageofflineRequests?

This is nothing that is specific to `async-await`. If your cache is inside a singleton and is accessed concurrently by *multiple threads*, there will be a race condition towards your cache. You'll have to make sure you're properly protecting your assets either by using a simple `lock` or by using concurrent collection to hold your data, such as a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

`async-await` by itself wont generate any extra threads unless you explicitly tell it to (using `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`). `await client.SendAsync` will simply yield control to the calling thread until your IO work (in this case, the HTTP request) is complete, then invoke the continuation via an IOCP.

Comment: I was not clear maybe. The SendAsync is not inside my singleton class. The SendAsync method calls my singleton class methods that work with my assets.

Comment: My answer remains the same. If `SendAsync` will be called concurrently, you'll still have to synchronize those requests.